# C++ - Where in my code should I include static_cast?

Tags: c++, static-cast

My static_cast does not seem to be working.  I create 5 int variables at the beginning of my code and attempt to change one (the total) to a double after performing calculations on the other 4, but it keeps displaying the int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, avg;

    cout << "Please input four grades: " << endl;

    cin >> grade1;
    cin >> grade2;
    cin >> grade3;
    cin >> grade4;

    avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4;

    cout << "Grades: " << grade1 << ", " << grade2 << ", " << grade3 << ", " << grade4 << endl;

    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Average grade: " << static_cast<double>(avg) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `avg` is declared as an `int`, so can never have a `double` value.

Comment: Even when I declare avg as a double it still does not work.

Comment: Do I need to static_cast the four ints as well?

Comment: @W.Atkinson Follow the answer... The answer provided by mathewHD works.

Answer (score 2):

When you are combining the integers and assigning them to `avg`.

You already have integer rounding conversion, so you need to static cast before you assign the number to the `avg` result.

You also don't even need to use static cast as long as you divide by 4.0 and make `avg` a double.

**Example:**

```
double avg = static_cast<double>(grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4) / 4.0;

// Alternative without static that still works
double avg = (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4) / 4.0;
```

Comment: You are storing an integer result.

Comment: The original answer stored an integer the edit fixed my mistake tough.

Comment: It's enough to use `4.0`, no need to additionally static_cast the left side.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the literal answer to your question "Where in my code should I include static_cast?" is quite simple:   nowhere, if at all possible.

`static_cast` - like all the C++ `_cast` operators, and all explicit (C-style) typecasts should be avoided wherever possible.   They have their uses, but it is better to minimise their usage, and certainly to avoid using them as blunt instruments to fix problems in code.

In your case, the correct results can be obtained quite simply by using appropriate types of variables, and any literal values having a suitable type.

Firstly, `avg` needs to be of type `double`.  This involves changing

> ```
> int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, avg;
> ```

to

```
int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4;
double avg;
```

Second, the calculation of the value of `avg` needs to be changed so it doesn't do an integer division.   This means changing

> ```
> avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4;
> ```

(which doesn't work because `grade1`, ... `grade4` are all of type `int`, their sum is an `int`, the literal `4` is an `int`, and dividing two `int`s produces an `int`) to

```
avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4.0;     //  note the 4.0
```

This works, because the literal `4.0` has type `double`.   The value `(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4)` is calculated as an `int` but, because it is being divided by a `double`, that integral value is converted implicitly to `double` before performing the division - and the result is of type `double`.

This is the only place in which I would *consider* using a `static_cast` here, by converting the `4` to a `double`.

```
avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / static_cast<double>(4);
```

which has the same net effect as the previous calculation of `avg`.   In your code, it makes little difference.   But a `static_cast` can be useful here in more general-purpose code, for example, if the number of input values (`grade1`, `grade2`, etc) is calculated as an integral value (e.g. the number of elements in an array).

The third thing you can do is remove the `static_cast` from the statement that outputs `avg` since it is now redundant (converting a `double` to `double` has no effect).   In other words turn

> ```
> cout << "Average grade: " << static_cast<double>(avg) << endl;
> ```

to

```
 cout << "Average grade: " << avg << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.
The first is that you declared avg as int, so the result is going to be rounded as int always.

However, declaring avg as double will not solve your problem immediately. In C++, operators are executed on objects of the same type and the result is an object of the same type.

`(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4)` is an int and `4` is an int, therefore the result will be an int. It doesn't matter if later is implicitly or explicitly casted to double, you will still get a rounded result.

In case the operands are not the same type, the compiler will implicitly promote one to match the other. The following lines will give you the correct result:

```
static_cast<double>(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4;
(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4.0;
static_cast<double>(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4.0;
```

Comment: @VolkanGüven It explains it differently. Answers are not just code

Answer (score 0):

An `int` cannot hold decimal places. `int` `/` results in an `int`, there are no decimals that result. You need to use the correct `/`, i.e at least [one of the operands must be `double` to get a `double` result](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    std::cout<<"Please input four grades: "<<std::endl;

    int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4;

    std::cin>>grade1;
    std::cin>>grade2;
    std::cin>>grade3;
    std::cin>>grade4;

    double avg=static_cast<double>(grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4)/4;    

    std::cout<<"Grades: "<<grade1<<", "<<grade2<<", "<<grade3<<", "<<grade4<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"Average grade: "<<avg<<std::endl;

}
```

You don't need the static cast here, as you can change the `int` literal `4` to a `double` literal `4.0`, but if you are summing the elements of a vector then calling `size()` on it, that will be an integer, and you will have to cast somewhere.